# How to convert strings to arrays and join on another table in sql

Tags: python, sql

At my work, I have two SQL tables, one is called jobs, with string attributes, job and codes. The latter is called skills with string attributes code and skill.

```
job code
--- ----
j1  s0001,s0003
j2  s0002,20003
j3  s0003,s0004

code  skills
----- ------
s0001 python programming language
s0002 oracle java
s0003 structured query language sql
s0004 microsoft excel
```

What my boss wants me to do is: Take values from the attribute code in jobs, split the string into an array, join this array on the codes (from skills table) and return the query in the format of job skills like:

```
job skills
--- ------
j1  python programming language,structured query language sql
```

At this point, I'd just like to know if (A) this is possible and (B) if there is a preferred alternative to this approach. I've listed my python solution, using dictionaries, below to illustrate my the concept:

```py
jobs = {'j1':'s0001,s0003',
        'j2':'s0002,20003',
        'j3':'s0003,s0004'}

skills = {'s0001':'python programming language',
          's0002':'oracle java',
          's0003':'structured query language sql',
          's0004':'microsoft excel'}

job_skills = {k:[] for k in jobs.keys()}
for j,s in jobs.items():
    for code,skill in skills.items():
        for i in s.split(','):
            if i == code:
                job_skills[j].append(skill)

for k,v in job_skills.items():
    job_skills[k] = ','.join(v)
```

And the output:

```py
{'j1': 'python programming language,structured query language sql',
 'j2': 'oracle java',
 'j3': 'structured query language sql,microsoft excel'}
```

The real crux of this problem is that there aren't just 4 different skills in our data. Our company's data includes ~5000 skills. My boss would greatly like to avoid creating a table with 5000 attributes, 1 for each skill; he believes the above approach will result in simpler queries, with potentially better memory management.

Comment: boss .... frighten

Comment: A little bit, haha... I've just been hired recently, so I'm hesitant to push back on month 1. After accruing some credibility, I'll be in a better position to push back. However, I'm genuinely curious how to handle this sort of problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still pretty new to SQL, and technically only do SQLite3 anyway so the best I can probably do is a Python solution. I'll tell you how I would solve it, and hopefully someone can come along and fix it, because doing things purely in SQL is vastly faster than ever using Python.

I'm going to assume that this is SQLite, because you tagged Python. If it's not, there's probably ways to convert the database to the .db format in order to use that if you prefer this solution.

I'm assuming that `conn` is your connection to the database `conn = sqlite3.connect(your_database_path)` or a cursor for it. I don't use cursors, but it's almost certainly better practice to use them.

First, I would fetch the 'skills' table and convert it to a dict. I would do so with:

```
skills_array = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM skills""")
skills_dict = dict()
#replace i with something else. I just did it so that I could use 'skill' as a variable
for i in skills_array:
    #skills array is an iterator of tuples, which means the first position is the code number, and the second position is the skill itself
    code = i[0]
    skill = i[1] 
    skills_dict[code] = skill
```

There's probably better ways to do this. If it's important, I recommend researching them. But if it's a one time thing this will work just fine. All this is doing is making giving an easy way to look up skills given a code. You could do this dozens of ways. You didn't mention it being a particularly large database, so this should be fine.

Before the next part, something should be mentioned about SQLite. It has very limited table modifying mechanics-- something I coincidentally found out about today. The recommended method is just to create a new table instead of trying to finagle with an old one. But there are easy ways to modify them with SQLiteBrowser-- something I highly recommend you use. At the very least it's much easier to view info in it for me, and it's available on all the important OS's.

Second, we need to combine the job table and the skills dict. There are much better ways to go about it, but I chose the easy approach. Delimiting the job.skills column by commas and going from there. I'll also create a new table, and insert directly to there.

```
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE combined (job TEXT PRIMARY KEY, skills text)""")
conn.commit()
job_array = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM jobs""")


for i in job_array:
    job = i[0]
    skill = i[1]
    for code in skill.split(","):
        skill.replace(code, skills_dict[code])

    conn.execute("""INSERT INTO combined VALUES (?, ?)""", (job, skill,))
    conn.commit()
```

And to combine it all...

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(your_database_path)

skills_array = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM skills""")
skills_dict = dict()
#replace i with something else. I just did it so that I could use 'skill' as a variable
for i in skills_array:
    #skills array is an iterator of tuples, which means the first position is the code number, and the second position is the skill itself
    code = i[0]
    skill = i[1] 
    skills_dict[code] = skill

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE combined (job TEXT PRIMARY KEY, skills text)""")
conn.commit()
job_array = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM jobs""")

for i in job_array:
    job = i[0]
    skill = i[1]
    for code in skill.split(","):
        skill.replace(code, skills_dict[code])

    conn.execute("""INSERT INTO combined VALUES (?, ?)""", (job, skill,))
    conn.commit()
```

To explain a little further if you/someone is confused on the job_array for loop:
Splitting skills allows you to see each individual code, meaning that all you have to do is replace every instance of the code being looked up with the corresponding skill.

And that's it. There's probably a mistake or two in the above code, so I would backup your database/tables before trying it, but this should work. One thing that you might find helpful are context managers, that would make it far more Pythonic. If you plan to use this consistently (for some strange reason), refactoring for speed and readability may also be prudent.

I would also like to believe that there's an SQLite only approach, since this is exactly what databases are made for.

Hope this helps. If it did, let me know. :>
P.S. If you're confused by something/want more explanation feel free to comment.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if there's anything else you need help with.